# Advantages of ScriptDb over Fusion Tables

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been looking through the new ScriptDb functionality - I am sure it is 'better' than Fusion Tables as a data store, I am just not sure how/why? Would anyone be able to suggest why it would be preferable (although not universally so, I am sure) over a Fusion Table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are few points to justify "why use scriptDB"

1. You do not have to use URLfetch to fetch data from Fusion Tables. Since you have relatively lower quota (as per my observation) for URLFetch
2. ScriptDB is natively supported in App Script so it is faster and robust than your own implementation to access fusion tables.
3. ScriptDB is key-value store (in the form of JSON) whose latency increases linearly as the DB size increases which is faster than all RDBMS whose latency increases exponentially with DB size. But I am not sure how Fusion Table behave as data size increases.
4. ScripDB service has far higher quota than URLFetch.
5. You can do maximum 5 queries in a second in fusion table but in scriptDB, there is no such declaration of query limit.
6. size limit of ScriptDB:
        50MB for consumer accounts,
        100MB for Google Apps accounts,
         200MB for Google Apps for Business/Education/Government accounts,. I think, this is sufficient for application developed using Apps Script.

You may check the FAQ section in below link for more detail.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb

Comment: Superb summary Waqar. The only query I would have is regarding size limits - my understanding is that Fusion Tables has a 250MB limit *per table*, while the ScriptDb limits you mentioned are applied *per user account*. So it would seem to me that FT's have a much higher limit?

Comment: Thanks AdamL for making me aware of this. Biggest limitation which I see to use FT is URLFetch quota. Anyways, I'll edit my answer

Comment: Absolutely agree on the URLFetch bottleneck. I guess the user has to trade off overall database size with how often they need to access the data.